# Multidimensional map template accessed and assigned inside of class method

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary

I was wondering if this was a valid way to assign a multidimensional map inside of a class method and if not how would I go about doing this.

```
    template<typename T>
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, T>> MT;

    template<typename T>
    void MonsterTemplate(std::string name, std::string node, template T v) {
        MT[name][node] = v;
    }
```

Edit1: I compiled and it gave me many errors but I will just give a portion of the 1st.
`error C3376: 'MonsterType::MT': only static data member templates are allowed`

Edit2:
I tried creating a struct

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, T>> MT;
};
```

I then added this inside the class

```
template<typename T>
    Wrapper<T>::MT mt;

    template<typename T>
    void MonsterTemplate(std::string name, std::string node, template T v) {
        mt[name][node] = v;
    }
```

Then got this error amongst many others.
`warning C4346: 'MT': dependent name is not a type`

The struct works outside the class without being multidimensional map, but I am unsure how to access it as multidimensional map.. just trying different things.

The idea is I want to store data of several objects data and index them by name, node and value.

Edit3:

So this is what I went with, and haven't gotten an error (just yet :p)

```
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> MT;

    void MonsterTemplate(std::string name, std::string node, int v) {
        MT[name][node] = v;
    }
```

Comment: Like the compiler says, a data member cannot be a template. A surrounding class can be though.

Comment: Since I don't seem to know too much :p I went with a basic multidimensional map for now. Which has not thrown any errors just yet :p

Comment: Not quite clear what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updating this for anyone looking for something similar

So I figured out how to construct this.

```
template<typename T>
struct Test 
{
    std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, std::map<size_t, std::map<std::string, T>>>> testmap;

    void MonsterTemplate(std::string creatureName, std::string name, std::string node, T v) {
        size_t i = testmap[creatureName][name].size();
        testmap[creatureName][name][i][node] = v;
    }
};

Test<std::string> str;
```

Since I needed various data types for `T` the structure worked much better than trying to find a way to assign a template to a static class, I am only using `std::string` as an example.

This can then be used inside of the class's method since `str` has a global scope.
`str.MonsterTemplate(creatureName, name, node, value);`